# Global variable not updating in JavaScript despite the function being called

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables

```
<script>
    var seatselected = 'Hola'

    function colorchange(element) {
        element.style.background = "#ff914d";
        element.style.color = "white";
        seatselected += element.innerHTML;
        seatselected += '+';
        //alert(seatselected);
    }
    document.getElementById("XYZ").innerHTML = seatselected;
</script>
```

This is the JS part of my code. When I call the colorchange function, the color changes. So, onlick() is not an issue in HTML. However, seatselected doesn't get updated. The innerHTML code gives me "Hola", even though I know colorchange has been executed. At the same time, if I use alert inside the function, it alerts me with the innerHTML value that I expect the global variable to have.

EDIT:
Here is the HTML part of the code, when I call the function. The function is called successfully, as when I click the element, the background color and text color change.

```
<td class="highlight" onclick="colorchange(this)">B1</td>
<td class="highlight" onclick="colorchange(this)">B2</td>
<td class="highlight" onclick="colorchange(this)">B3</td>
<td class="highlight" onclick="colorchange(this)">B4</td>
<p id="XYZ"></p>
```

What I'm trying to do is that I want to add onto a string the innerhtml of whichever element is being clicked. Now when I try to put it in XYZ, the changes made inside the function do not show up.

Comment: Can you show us the full code please? Such as how function is called, the HTML elements

Comment: "*The alert gives me "Hola" outside the function, even though I know colorchange has been executed*" the `alert()` outside the function *is not called when the function is called*. You create `seatselected` -> define the function `colorchange` -> *immediately* `alert` the value of `seatselected` -> later on call `colorchange`

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. The `colour` change function is never called in what you have provided (not before and not after the `alert` is called).

Comment: @WasifHasan I edited the post to include that!

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, but since I am updating the variable, it should update and alert accordingly. The commented-out alert inside the function alerts what it should, it just doesn't reflect back globally.

Comment: *but since I am updating the variable, it should update and alert accordingly.*" calling the function does ***not*** call that `alert`. Why would it? You're calling `colorchange()` not any other random code around the declaration.

Comment: Okay, fair. But when I use document.getElementById("SomeID").innerHTML = seatselected; that too gives me Hola, even after the function has been called. And when I alert inside the function, the alert gives me what I expect it to give me globally too.
@VLAZ

Comment: *where* do you have `document.getElementById("SomeID").innerHTML = seatselected`? Is it called *after* `colorchange` is executed?

Comment: The `document.getElementById("XYZ").innerHTML = seatselected;` line has literally the exact same problems as the `alert` that was there before. It will not be executed when you call the function. If it needs to happen every time `colorchange` is called, then it should probably be inside that function.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take a piece of paper. (The paper represents the `seatselected` variable)
2. Write "Hola" on that piece of paper. (This is the string)
3. Read the piece of paper out to yourself. (This represents the alert)
4. Photocopy the piece of paper (This represents assigning to an element's `innerHTML` as you mentioned in a comment).
5. Ask a friend to wave at you (press a button), and when they do write something different on the piece of paper.

Now. Did you hear yourself say, out loud, whatever is currently written on the piece of paper? Does the text on the photocopy change?

**No**.

The instructions (the program) don't tell you to read out the paper every time it changes.

Nor do they make it possible for the second thing you wrote on the paper to travel back in time and replace "Hola" **before** you read out and photocopied what was printed on it.

---

If you want to see an alert after the button has been pressed then you need to write code which calls alert **after** the button has been pressed.

i.e. in the function you call from the event handler

i.e. where you have commented out alert

Likewise, if you want to change the value assigned to `innerHTML` then you need to explicitly change it. Assigning a string to `innerHTML` assigns the *current string value*, not a reference to the variable you copied that value from.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I'll edit the question to explain the problem a bit better.

Comment: I editted the post. Maybe now I could explain my problem better. I'm a beginner, first time coding JavaScript.

Comment: @aarnavg17 — The edits to the question don't change the answer.

Comment: But it should, right? If I am updating the global variable inside the function, then it should update the innerHTML of id XYZ accodingly.

Comment: @aarnavg17 "*If I am updating the global variable inside the function, then it should update the innerHTML of id XYZ accodingly*" no. The update will happen only if you call the line of code again. There is no "dynamic binding" between a variable and HTML that automatically syncs both.

Comment: @aarnavg17 — No. I just wrote a 230 word answer explaining why in three different ways.

Answer (score -2):

Just added `alert()` inside the function

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Checkbox Dynamically using JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<td class="highlight" onclick="colorchange(this)">B1</td>
<td class="highlight" onclick="colorchange(this)">B2</td>
<td class="highlight" onclick="colorchange(this)">B3</td>
<td class="highlight" onclick="colorchange(this)">B4</td>
</table>

</body>

<script>
    var seatselected = 'Hola'
    function colorchange(element) {
                element.style.background = "#ff914d";
        element.style.color = "white";
        seatselected += element.innerHTML;
        seatselected += '+';
        alert(seatselected);
    }
     */</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, alert was just for me to check whether the global variable is being updated or not. I need to use the variable seatselected later, but the changes I made inside the function do not change for some reason.